# how to add a string to a string list in java in eclipse

Tags: java

today I'm making a Minecraft java mod
I made a custom command list using

`public String Commands[];`

but later I tried to add a string using

`Commands.add("");`

why

Comment: use `List<String>` instead of an array.

Comment: You are creating an array, not a list. If you want to create a list use `List<String> Commands = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 0):

the primary array is different from object ArrayList/LinkedList, which implements List.

method add() is belong to implement List;

```
List<String> commands = new ArrayLidt<>();
commands.add("whatever");
```

or

```
String[] commands = new String[SIZE];
commands[0] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample usage for string arraylist implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> supplierNames = new ArrayList<>();
    supplierNames.add("sup1");
    supplierNames.add("sup2");
    supplierNames.add("sup3");
    for (String supply : supplierNames) {
      System.out.println(supply);
    }
  }
}
```